# Change the color of Pagination (vue3-carousel) indicator (Vue3 & Tailwind)

Tags: vuejs3, tailwind-css, carousel, vite

**Bug**
Trying to change the color of the Paginator has been achieved only locally, since when deploying the changes do not take effect

Deploy on Netlify

**To Reproduce**
In **main.css**

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

:root {
    --vc-clr-secondary: #bfbfbf !important;
    --vc-clr-primary: #ffffff !important;
}
```

I make the changes to these variables since by reviewing the package code I identified these are the variables that use the Paginator color

**Expected behavior**
This is what the deployment should look like
[image: localhost_5173_(iPhone 12 Pro)]
When the display is done the Paginator uses the default colors